# VK api sdk fingerprint is incorrect в релизной версии приложения

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Недавно создал и загрузил в Play Market свое приложение на базе VK Api. При запуске приложения через Android Studio все запускается нормально, однако, если скачать его из магазина, то можно увидеть ошибку о неправильном sdk_fingerprint. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо указать в настройках приложения на сайте ВК хэш релизного ключа, которым вы подписали приложение.